# puppet agent duplicate file

Tags: linux, puppet

I have a machine with a puppet agent installed.
When I try to run the puppet agent I got this error.
I've already tried force the file with the attribute but this does not work.
The module that is indicated is not managed for me, it's a third party module.

my files.pp :

```
class icarrierdata_nginx::files inherits icarrierdata_nginx::params {
  $source_base = "puppet:///modules/${module_name}"

  if ! defined(File['/etc/nginx/nginx.conf']) {
    file { 'nginx_config_file':
    ensure => present,
    content => template("${module_name}/nginx.conf.erb"),
    owner => 'root',
    group => 'root',
    notify => [Service['nginx']],
    force  =>  true,
    path   =>  "/etc/nginx/nginx.conf",
   }
  }
}
```

and this is the error:

```
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: Error 500 on SERVER: Server Error: 
Evaluation Error: Error while evaluating a Resource Statement, Duplicate declaration: 
File[/etc/nginx/nginx.conf] is already declared at (file: 
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/staging/modules/icarrierdata_nginx/manifests/files.pp, 
line: 5); cannot redeclare (file: 
/etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/staging/modules/nginx/manifests/config.pp, line: 238) 
(file: /etc/puppetlabs/code/environments/staging/modules/nginx/manifests/config.pp, line: 
238, column: 3) on node stg-data-odatos-proxy-us-central1.c.scorpius-odatos.internal
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
```

Someone could help me ?

Comment: The problem appears to be that you are trying to use two different modules to manage your nginx configuration.  Choose one.  It looks like module icarrierdata_nginx` attempts to use the `defined()` function to avoid just such issues, but that's an anti-pattern, in part because, as you see, it is not reliable.